# ASP.NET Navigation Loads UserControls (Button-Event)

Tags: asp.net, user-controls

Got a Navigation, by Example:

- Home
- News
- Contact

When choosing one Navigationlink, on the right side (Content), it loads a **UserControl**.
So, when I click on Home, it loads `HomeUserControl.ascx`...

Now the problem is, that the **Button-Events aren't firing (Buttons on the UserControls)**...
I could load UserControls in the `Page_Init` (then Button-event would work) but I can't do that, because the UserControls Loading is *depended* on what the user has choosed...

How to achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem, I added a 2nd Masterpage in my existing Masterpage..